# Group items in python pandas dataframe by number of occurences

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have the following dataset:

```
x     | y
-------------
foo   | 2
foo   | 3
foo   | 2
bar   | 5
baz   | 3
baz   | 2
baz   | 1
```

I want a summary table that shows, for each number of times each `x` value can occur, how many `x` values occur that number of times, and the average `y` value for these `x` items. Like so:

```
#  | count | avg_y
-------------------
1  | 1     | 5
2  | 0     | nan
3  | 2     | 2.1667
```

I am part of the way there by calling:

```
df.x.value_counts().value_counts().sort_index()
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the `avg_y` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
a = df.groupby('x')['y'].agg(['size','mean']).groupby('size')['mean'].agg(['size','mean'])
#added missing rows
a = a.reindex(range(1, a.index.max() + 1))
a['size'] = a['size'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (a)
      size      mean
size                
1        1  5.000000
2        0       NaN
3        2  2.166667
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('x')['y'].agg(['size','mean']))
     size      mean
x                  
bar     1  5.000000
baz     3  2.000000
foo     3  2.333333
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening on `a = a.reindex(range(1, a.index.max() + 1))`

Comment: I need all sizes, but I get only `1` and `3`. so for add `2` I use reindex by range(1,4) - `1,2,3` values ;0